# Web application(vue.js) is not recognising the value selected from dropdown using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, vuejs3, html-select

I am facing one issue while automating the web application designed using vue.js

**Requirement/scenario**: We have a screen where we need to select all the values(3 fields text field, dropdown, and calendar) then the Next button will be enabled.

When I ran manually this scenario its working fine but when I tried to automate this scenario I am facing an issue with dropdown.

**Issue**:
Using selenium I am able to select a value from the dropdown but it's not getting recognized hence Next button is not getting enabled. When I am trying to select a value manually by keeping debug point at that place it's working perfectly.

**I tried the below ways but no luck**

1. Using JavascriptExecutor
2. Using Actions call
3. Using Key events
4. I tried with Robot class
5. Select class

Thank you in advance

Adding screenshots as well:
Manual:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9moE.png)

Automation:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cknmY.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send an input event using javascript for that dropdown, after you selected it. Something like this, for java:
This is the event trigger:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {'bubbles': true, 'cancelable':true }));", (WebElement) driver.findElement(your selector));
```

Comment: @pguardiario why, whats up?

Comment: that's hard to look at. maybe some formatting?